# WPF Image Uniform to None

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to make my Image to stretch uniform when its size is smaller than original. If there is enough space, I don't want to stretch the image. I'am using the Image control:

```
<Image Name="ImageBox"  Stretch="Uniform"  SizeChanged="ImageBox_SizeChanged_1"/>
```

My event handler:

```
private void ImageBox_SizeChanged_1(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (OriginalImageSize == null) return;

        if (ImageBox.RenderSize.Width > OriginalImageSize.Width && ImageBox.RenderSize.Height > OriginalImageSize.Height)
            ImageBox.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        else
            ImageBox.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    }
```

When I load image it's ok, next I resize the window so there is enough space to show whole image and scaling is not necessary, image starts blinking (from Stretch.None to Stretch.Uniform I guess).

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [StretchDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stretchdirection.aspx) property. You might want to try

```
<Image Name="ImageBox"  Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly"/>
```

without your event.